# MVC wire format model binding and validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How do you deal with model validation when using the wire format model binding. I am looking to have validation messages in the validation summary area and highlight the affected input field that has failed to validate.

```
//Model
public class Container 
{
   List<Item> Items { get; set;}
}

//View
@Html.ValidationSummary()

@foreach (var item in Model.Items) { 
   <div>
   @<text><input type="hidden" name="container.Items[@item.Index].Property1" value = "@item.Property1" /></text>
   @<text><input type="text" name="container.Items[@item.Index].Property2" value = "@item.Property2" /></text>
   </div>
}

//Controller Action
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething(Container container){
   //Call DB - retrieve DB messages - but then how do you add validation summary messages from DB exceptions.

   return view(container);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ModelState.AddModelError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.addmodelerror%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) in your controller, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething(Container container){
   var error = Model.GetErrors();  //Change this to whatever call you need to validate the Container
   if(error.HasErrors)
   {
       ModelState.AddModelError("KEY",error.Message);
   }

   return view(container);
}
```

This will add errors that will be displayed in the ValidationSummary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Matthew, I will give that a go but with regards to the "KEY" does this need to match the wire format model to get highlighting/linking to the appropriate field causing the error. i.e. does "KEY" = "container.Items[0].Property1"?

Comment: Have marked this as the answer as it helped resolve the question. The key was used in association with the @Html.ValidationMessage(modelName, message), were modelName = KEY and message = "*".